# Which class I should use to to solve the issue with angularjs input validation?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I created a form and I applied the angularjs validation of it. This work fine but I am facing one issue, if some one help me I will appreciate that.
The form html code is here

```
  <div class="w3-twothird w3-container" ng-app>
   <h2>Larger books order form</h2>
   <h3>Please fill the following form to order a book!</h3>
   <form class="form-horizontal" action="mail-proceeing-form.php" method="post" name="orderForm" novalidate>
      <!-- Book Title -->
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="bookTitle" ng-model="order.bookTitle" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Title" ng-required="true">
            <!--Error Start -->
            <div ng-show="orderForm.bookTitle.$touched && orderForm.bookTitle.$invalid">
               <span class="text-danger">Please enter a book title!</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Error End -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Book ISBN-->
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="bookIBSN" ng-model="order.bookIBSN" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="ISBN" ng-required="true">
            <!--Error Start -->
            <div ng-show="orderForm.bookIBSN.$touched && orderForm.bookIBSN.$invalid">
               <span class="text-danger">Please enter IBSN!</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Error End -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- User Name -->
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="order.name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Name" ng-required="true">
            <!--Error Start -->
            <div ng-show="orderForm.name.$touched && orderForm.name.$invalid">
               <span class="text-danger"> Please enter your name!</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Error End -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- User Email -->
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="order.email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" ng-required="true">
            <!--Error Start -->
            <div ng-show="orderForm.email.$touched && orderForm.email.$invalid">
               <span class="text-danger"> Please enter a valid email!</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Error End -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- User Message -->
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" ng-model="order.message" ng-required="true"></textarea>
            <!--Error Start -->
            <div ng-show="orderForm.message.$touched && orderForm.message.$invalid">
               <span class="text-danger"> Please enter your message!</span>
            </div>
            <!-- Error End -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Submit Button -->
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit Request" ng-disabled="orderForm.$invalid">
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

The angular js and all required files are connected to the html.
The CSS that I used is given.

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched, textarea.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

If you want to check live please fink the link.
http://manhattanmode.se/old-books/index.php

Now the problem is that, If the user click on input field Title, and leave it empty then the user move to next field i.e. click on ISBN. Then the validation message appear and the input field border get rid. 
So the user realize that I need to fill the "Title first", then he again click inside Title field. but unfortunately the ISBN field border get red and validation message appear. 
I want if user click on next field and leave the other empty then the validation will show otherwise it will not show.
In simple if user click on next validation must apply on previous but if user move back to previous the validation may not apply on next.

[This what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t40KB.png)

Comment: So, If I got your question, you want to show only 1 validation per time?

Comment: I hope this video will more help to understand my question [Click to watch the video](https://youtu.be/4OY3BhXrqN0)

Comment: Hello developer033 I post the video link I hope it will more help. I will say yes, in simple If user click on Title and leave it empty and move to ISBN then the Title validation need to be appear. but if he/she click on Title again, the It must not show the ISBN validation.

Comment: I need validation only if some one click on next field then the previous field must show validation error. but if you move to previous then it will not show the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know there's no property like `hasFocus` or whatever like this in the `form` properties. Also I noticed there's an [**issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/903) since 2012 asking for something like that.

Then, to achieve what you want you can play with [**`ngFocus`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) and [**`ngBlur`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) directive, as below:

```
<input type="text" ng-focus="isbnFocus=true" ng-blur="isbnFocus=false" name="bookIBSN" ng-model="order.bookIBSN" class="form-control" id="isbn" placeholder="ISBN" required>
<!--Error Start -->
 <div ng-if="orderForm.bookIBSN.$invalid && orderForm.bookIBSN.$touched && !isbnFocus">
```

The *complete* `code`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="w3-twothird w3-container">
    <h2>Larger books order form</h2>
    <h3>Please fill the following form to order a book!</h3>
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="mail-proceeing-form.php" method="post" name="orderForm" novalidate>
      <!-- Book Title -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" ng-focus="titleFocus=true" ng-blur="titleFocus=false" name="bookTitle" ng-model="order.bookTitle" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Title" ng-required="true">
          <!--Error Start -->
          <div ng-if="orderForm.bookTitle.$invalid && orderForm.bookTitle.$touched && !titleFocus">
            <span class="text-danger">Please enter a book title!</span>
          </div>
          <!-- Error End -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Book ISBN-->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" ng-focus="isbnFocus=true" ng-blur="isbnFocus=false" name="bookIBSN" ng-model="order.bookIBSN" class="form-control" id="isbn" placeholder="ISBN" required>
          <!--Error Start -->
          <div ng-if="orderForm.bookIBSN.$invalid && orderForm.bookIBSN.$touched && !isbnFocus">
            <span class="text-danger">Please enter IBSN!</span>
          </div>
          <!-- Error End -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- User Name -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="name" ng-focus="nameFocus=true" ng-blur="nameFocus=false" ng-model="order.name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          <!--Error Start -->
          <div ng-if="orderForm.name.$invalid && orderForm.name.$touched && !nameFocus">
            <span class="text-danger"> Please enter your name!</span>
          </div>
          <!-- Error End -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- User Email -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" name="email" ng-focus="emailFocus=true" ng-blur="emailFocus=false" ng-model="order.email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" required>
          <!--Error Start -->
          <div ng-if="orderForm.email.$invalid && orderForm.email.$touched && !emailFocus">
            <span class="text-danger"> Please enter a valid email!</span>
          </div>
          <!-- Error End -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- User Message -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea class="form-control" ng-focus="messageFocus=true" ng-blur="messageFocus=false" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" ng-model="order.message" required></textarea>
          <!--Error Start -->
          <div ng-if="orderForm.message.$invalid && orderForm.message.$touched && !messageFocus">
            <span class="text-danger"> Please enter your message!</span>
          </div>
          <!-- Error End -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Submit Button -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit Request" ng-disabled="orderForm.$invalid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Tips:**

1. Use preferably `ngIf` directive instead of `ngShow`.
2. In your case, `ng-required="true"` is unnecessary, you can simply use `required` as I did. `ngRequired` directive is used when you want to put a condition to the field to make it required or not.
3. I don't know if you have all the fields with the same `id` like here, but it's semantically incorrect.

**Note:** I don't think it's the best solution, but I think it can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: That look fine.. but in this if I click on Title then move to ISBN then the Title validation appear, and when I again click in Title then the Title validation disappear. But the ISBN validation show which look not good. If the IBSN validation not appear will be very good.

Comment: With that code you put is answer I am very close to the solution. Now what I want exactly is that , if I click did not enter value to first field and move to the next one the first field will show error message. but if I click again in the first field the second field which I leave do not show error message. 1. first field will show error if I go to second field, second field will show error if I go to third field in simple next field. but if user go to previous field then I will not show the error.

Comment: If user move to next field the previous field will show error. but if the user move to previous field the next field will not show the error.

Comment: I added the image also with title This what I want.

Comment: What's the logic of this? If you're in `title`, the field below should not show error, but if you're in `name` field, the above field should show error..

Comment: yes you got it. for example if I am in any field the bellow fields will not show error but the upper fields will show errors.

Comment: I don't know why you're looking for this, but I have to go ahead and say: it is really a bad thing to do, because there's no way do it without using some hack and ugly solution

Comment: Yes I am thinking the same. It look like illogical. But if I find good solution for that will be good. Otherwise I am lost in translation for that.

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't find.. What's the reson that you're looking for it?